# Purpose of Authentication filter in web Api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am really confused about Authentication filter in web Api after going through Microsoft documents, Is it obsolete in 2020 , when i type, how to secure Asp.net web api , Every tutorial site suggests to use OAuth, its great but suppose i want to use Basic authentication then where to write its logic, by creating an Authentication Filter or Authorization filter.Every tutorial site uses Authorization filter ,my question is why they use Authorization filter to authenticate a request when there is Authentication filter available.Am i referring an old article and is there no such filter available in web api ?Please Tell me the various techniques you experienced folks use to secure your api and please also tell me the scenario when to use them.I can not afford any course and i am new in this.